# In which category do the divine attributes fall?

Tags: belief, divine-attributes

After going through multiple opinions of the scholars, I'm really confused about nature of attributes of God. Some say that all are muhkamat but their howness is among mutashabihat. Yet others categorize them into two i.e. one muhkamat like seeing, hearing and mutashabihat like hands, feet, shin. Also there's too much conflict about whether they should be submitted along with their meanings as a whole to Allah or it is just there kaifiyyah which is to be submitted without the meaning. Why is this topic too much conflicting. Even leading to groups calling each others by titles like literalists, mufawwids etc. Will someone expert in this field of study guide me?